# How can I get the list of each and every available font?

Tags: java, android

With `TypeFace.create(String name,int style)`, I can create a `TypeFace` to use with a `Paint`. But is there a way to get the list of each and every font name available on a device? I need to show this list to the user to let him choose the font he wants to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) for more information on typefaces.

Specifically, an answer from the Android Developers mailing list:

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html
>
> There are only three fonts: normal (Droid Sans), serif (Droid Serif),
>   and monospace (Droid Sans Mono).
>
> While there may be additional fonts buried in WebKit somewhere, they
>   appear to be inaccessible to developers outside of WebKit. :-(
>
> The only other fonts are any TrueType ones you bundle with your
>   application.

There is also [roboto](https://github.com/mcalliph/roboto-text-view).

Other sources:

http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg44221.html

http://www.forbes.com/2008/09/25/font-android-g1-tech-wire-cx_ew_0926font.html

http://www.droidfonts.com/droidfonts/about/